# how to determine if a test run in only one geographic area leads to activity different than in other geographic areas

Tags: outliers, ab-test, z-statistic

I was recently given data from an experiment that I did not design.  In this study, the people running it changed behavior in 1 designative market area (DMA) but not the other DMAs (209 other DMAs).  They choose this DMA because, based on another analysis, they deemed it to be a market area that exhibits faily 'normal' activity.  Now, after running it for a few months, they want to see if activity in the area is different than other DMA's - i.e., to see if the study had an effect. They gave me data on traffic and conversions for each DMA (an aggregate total across all days although it could be broken down by day) for this year and last year (study was only run this year).

My first thought on how to proceed is to, one, divide this years data by last year's activity (so that I control for typical size of activity in area; plus, we are interested in growth anyway).  Then, two, take the scaled data from all of the 'control' DMAs (209 of them) to find the mean and standard deviation of conversion and traffic activity.  Then, using this mean/st dev, calculate the zscore of the test area.  If it is above 1.96, I could say that the change in activity in the test DMA for this year appears to be rather abnormal (i.e., would not occur often if it had been drawn from the 'control group' distribution).  The distribution of activity across the control DMAs is, more or less, normally distributed after to some transformations, so a zscore seems reasonable.

Any thoughts on a better way to proceed?